# Walk Directory recursively issue

Tags: c++, directory, qt-creator, subdirectory, qlist

I am trying to walk a directory recursively and modify its contents,that modification should be done for all files and files of sub directories.

```
void EncryptMountedFolder(QString DirPath)
{
        QStringList listFile;
        QStringList listDir;
        int r=0;
    if(WalkDir(DirPath,listFile,listDir))
     {

        foreach (QString filePath, listFile)
        {
        //modif of file with filePath as path
        }

        foreach(QString subdirPath, listDir)
        {
            EncryptMountedFolder(subdirPath);
        }

      }
      else qDebug()<<"can not find "<<DirPath<<"or it is not folder path ";

}
```

`WalkDir` function:

```
bool WalkDir(QString DirPath, QStringList &FList, QStringList &DList)
{
    QString p=QDir::fromNativeSeparators(DirPath);
    QDir dir( p );
    if(dir.exists())
    {           
          dir.setFilter( QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks );
          const QFileInfoList fileinfolist = dir.entryInfoList();

          foreach(const QFileInfo& fi,fileinfolist)
              if(fi.baseName() != "")
              {
                if( fi.isDir() && fi.isReadable() )
                 DList=DList << fi.absoluteFilePath() ;
                 else
                    FList= FList<< fi.absoluteFilePath();
              }              
        return true;
    }
    else
        {    qDebug()<<"not valid dir path or doesn't exist"<<DirPath ;
             return false;
         }    
}
```

Files under all sub directories were modified as I want, but it crashes and I get: `Critical error detected c0000374`  that point me to `qlist.h` in `Q_OUTOFLINE_TEMPLATE void QList<T>::free(QListData::Data *data)` function line  `qFree(data);`

Can anyone find out what I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I executed the snippet of code you pasted on a Linux machine (set the directory to walk to a medium sized directory tree: 3 levels of depth with a few hundred files), without any error.  
So this might either be specific to whatever logic you're applying to encrypt the files, or a bug that manifests itself if the directory tree you're attempting to scan, is past a certain size.

Comment: I think your implementation of the walking is most likely the source of the issue. It is unnecessarily complicated. Also it's not a good practice to use the parameters you're passing to your function as return values:  

    WalkDir(QString DirPath, QStringList &FList, QStringList &DList)

This is bug-prone and it doesn't make for easily testable and maintainable code.

Comment: While it is worth trying to debug this issue and understand what went wrong, I would also suggest you rework your implementation. There are 2 distinct activities in what you are attempting to implement: ( 1. directory traversal, 2. processing applied on a single file to encrypt it). Each of these, can be implemented in a single function. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my last comment, this is my suggestion to simplify the walking function (based on [this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/qt/0596000642/working-with-files-and-directories/prowqt2-chp-11-sect-2)):

```
void walk( const QString& dirname )
{
  QDir dir( dirname );
  dir.setFilter( QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks );

  const QFileInfoList fileinfolist = dir.entryInfoList();
  foreach( const QFileInfo& fi,fileinfolist ) {
    if( fi.baseName() == "." || fi.baseName() == ".."  || fi.baseName() == "" ) {
      continue;
    }
    if( fi.isDir() && fi.isReadable() ) {
      // This is the conditional for recursion
      walk( fi.absoluteFilePath() );
    }
    else {
      // This is where you might call your encrypting function
      qDebug() << "Encrypting file: " << fi.absoluteFilePath();
      encrypt( fi.absoluteFilePath() );
    }
  }
}
```

You can also make it more generic by passing the encrypting function as a callback to walk(). So that you can reuse it for other types of processing you might need to apply.

Also if you're keen on testing your code, you might notice that my previous suggestion, is not unit-testable: for a method to be easily testable, it should have non-dependent input and output, and your test would check the output against the expected value.

So here is a version that returns the list of all files collected from the given directory tree:

```
QStringList walk( const QString& dirname )
{
  QDir dir( dirname );
  dir.setFilter( QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks );

  const QFileInfoList fileinfolist = dir.entryInfoList();
  QStringList collectedFileList;
  foreach( const QFileInfo& fi,fileinfolist ) {

    if( fi.baseName() == "." || fi.baseName() == ".."  || fi.baseName() == "" ) {
      continue;
    }

    if( fi.isDir() && fi.isReadable() ) {
      collectedFileList << walk( fi.absoluteFilePath() );
    }
    else {
      collectedFileList << fi.absoluteFilePath();
    }
  }
  return collectedFileList;
}
```

And now you can add a third method to loop over the files and encrypt them:

```
void encryptDirectoryTree( const QString& dirname )
{
     QStringList filesInDir = walk( dirname );
     foreach( const QString& filePath, filesInDir ) {
        encrypt( filePath );
     }
}
```

Comment: Really I appreciate your help and your time thank you @ylabidi. In fact before seeing your suggestion I retest my code and I found the source bug in my encryption algorithm implementation that deal with char* and strcpy so I fixed it temporarily and I re-implemented a different approach that encrypt or decrypt a file when a user demand  , but now I'am totally convinced by your second approach, I will test it and see if it'is more efficient, thank you one more time.